# How much is the lowest frequency of electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Carryng energy by photon.
Minimum energy of a photon?!!!!

Comment: A photon by itself doesn't have a frequency. It needs a reference frame in which to be observed for that.

Answer (score 3):

The energy E=h*f f can get very very low. so there is no minimum. but the smaller f is the more difficult it is to discover the photon as a particle, compared to a wave. That is why we never speak of radio waves as particles or photons , since they do not behave as particles.

Comment: So you are saying that although we can fire single photons of light, we can not fire single photons of radio waves?